# Crash with a message The specified child already has a parent

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding

Porting the code to use DataBinding feature and inflating a layout with the generated code.

Following is the code of my fragment

```
private lateinit var binding: FragmentFormBinding

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(activity!!, R.layout.fragment_form)
    return binding.root
    // return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_form, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    binding.user = User("john", "doe")
}
```

My fragment form code is as follows with one field for the first name.

**fragment_form**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <data>
            <variable name="user" type="components.User" />
        </data>

      <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/first"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/first"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:text="@{user.first}" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

**Error**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataBindingUtil.setContentView()` replaces the activity's content view with the given layout. That also means the inflated layout is added to a parent layout.

A fragment's `onCreateView()` needs to a return a layout that is not added to any parent layout.

Replace your `DataBindingUtil.setContentView(...)` with something like

```
DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_form, container, false)
```